# Changing CSS proprety of another div located in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i would like to change the DOM of an html page but from another page i tried sharing the same script between the 2 pages but it didnt work here is an illustration for what i am trying to do

**1-First page**

```
<div>
<p id="simpletext">Hello world</p>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type ="text/javascript"></script> <!-- same script file is present in the second page -->
</div>
```

**2-Second page**

```
<div>
<button>Click me </button>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type ="text/javascript"></script><!-- same script file is present in the first page -->
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
 $("button").on("click",function(){
    $("simpletext").css("color","blue");
    });
```

i am trying to when i click on the button wish is located on the second page to change the color of the text on the first page

Comment: You can only amend the DOM of the page which is currently loaded. If you want to change a different page based on an action in a previous one you'd need to persist the state of the user's interactions and then amend the other page when it loads. To do that you can use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `session`, `cookies`, or AJAX to store information on the server.

Comment: you have a missing `#` sign within your jquery code. Try: `$("#simpletext").css("color","blue");` Hope this helps!

Comment: @Rory beat me too it. If it was me, I'd use localStorage for something this simple.

Comment: Well spotted @N.Ivanov, but this won't solve this issue.

Comment: Both opened at the same time or one after another?

Comment: How are they both open at the same time? `iframe`?

Comment: the first page is meant for the user , while the second page is meant for the admin so he can change the css of the first page

Comment: what i am showing in the question is just an illustration for the problem that iam facing on my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send messages from one page to another. At the buttons side send a message:

```
 $("button").on("click",function(){
   wondow.postMessage("show","*");
});
```

Then at the other page, wait for a message:

```
 window.addEventListener("message",function(event){
   if(event.data === "show") {
     $("simpletext").css("color","blue");
   }
});
```

I assume that both windows are opened on the same machine, if not, you need ajax or websockets instead and do serverside proxying.

Comment: Thanks that what i was looking for